# Why is the opposite of "greater than" "less than"?

Tags: antonyms, comparisons

I am confused on why these naming conventions are the way they are. The symbols `>` and `<` are usually written as "greater than" and "less than".

The opposite of "less" is "more", isn't it? Though those words describe quantities only, which might not be desired if you're talking about a measure of size instead.

So, sticking with "greater than", shouldn't the opposite be called "smaller than"?

Comment: The names come from a time when the more common antonym of "greater" was "lesser", as in "a great man" vs "the lesser of two evils", or the general trend in early taxonomic systems to give informal names like [greater vs lesser sand plover](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254780588_Identification_taxonomy_and_distribution_of_Greater_and_Lesser_Sand_Plovers). We don't use *greater* or *lesser* in this sense much nowadays (do you ever say "his slice of cake is greater than mine"?), but the names have stuck for the mathematical symbols, as they do.

Comment: To be pedantic, the opposite of "greater than" is "less than or equal to"...

Comment: This raises the question: Why "less than" and not "lesser than"? Seems like a glitch in the grammar

Comment: @user888379 the choice of what the "opposite" is for any concept or word can often be fairly abitrary.  So, I think you're just expressing an opinion there - saying that you're being pedantic is in fact the same as saying that your opinion is correct, and I don't think that is actually the case.

Comment: Those symbols are MATHEMATICAL symbols.  They mean whatever meaning mathematics assigns to them.  And in mathematics the opposite of "greater than" is "less than or equal to".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics, not English.

Comment: Please reconsider, @Hot Licks. OP is not asking what is the mathematical antonym of 'greater than', but *"shouldn't the opposite be called "smaller than""* -- it's not only in mathematics that the commonly used antonym of 'greater than' is 'less than' and not 'lesser than': there is the common expression *'the whole is greater than the sum of its parts'*, as applied to effectively co-ordinated group activities, and the antonym would be 'less than' as in *'disunity makes them less than the sum of their parts'* -- so it's an English question in asking why is the antonym used inconsistently here?

Comment: @EnglishStudent - Then why does he illustrate it with mathematical symbols?

Comment: @HotLicks the question is on-topic. it is about how the various English words are used or not to describe the very ordinary mathematical concepts.

Comment: I think OP is confused with the way English has been used in mathematical naming conventions, @Hot Licks.  This question, by the way, is 'semantically academic' because *less than,* *smaller than* and *lesser than* have the same meaning when used to compare numbers; and it would have been a purely mathematical question *but for the fact that* the antonym of 'greater than' is 'less than' in English first (and still current) and thus probably found its way into Mathematics.Not every nation uses English as the language of mathematics. If you are not really convinced you can retain the close vote.

Comment: @EnglishStudent - You have stated a fake fact.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the false premise that the two terms are "opposites" and embodies false assumptions about the origin and nature of opposites in general.

Comment: Please reconsider, @David.The two terms are indeed opposites in English, when used to compare numbers or amounts. If you disagree please explain why you think they are *not* antonyms. And within the context of OP's question, mathematic has separate symbols for 'greater than or equal to' and 'less than or equal to' as you can see [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=greater+than+or+equal+to&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=7rimWZHmJezt8Aegl4KoBg). If you are not really convinced you can retain the close vote.

Comment: *"@EnglishStudent - You have stated a fake fact."* -- the antonym of 'greater than' as used in English to compare things (rather than in the sense of 'greatness') is *not* less than? I am always open to being corrected, @Hot Licks. Thanks. So what is the correct antonym? And if you really mean that *"in mathematics the opposite of "greater than" is "less than or equal to""* then I agree with you but that's **in Mathematics** and is not a matter of debate here anyway. All I can say in conclusion is, I repeat: If you are not really convinced you can retain the close vote.

Comment: @EnglishStudent - As is the case for most English words, there is no single "antonym" of "greater than", and you must consider the context and tone of speech to pick the best candidate.

Comment: Your point is well made and well taken, @Hot Licks.

Comment: Actually, the opposite of "greater than" is "not greater than". That's a good general rule to follow that takes into account all vagaries of the English language. Well, all of them that I can think about at the moment :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible reason that mathematics might have come to use *greater than* and *less than* as opposed to (say) *larger than* and *smaller than* might be that they were more natural translations from Latin.

Mathematics was largely done in Latin until the 17th century. The Latin terms were *majorem quam* and *minorem quam*, as can be seen by the first definition of the > and < signs in *Artis Analyticae Praxis ad Aequationes Algebraicas Resolvendas* by Thomas Harriot (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign)):

> "Signum majoritatis ut a > b significet a majorem quam b" and "Signum minoritatis ut a < b significet a minorem quam b."

*Major* is the comparative form of [*magnus*,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magnus) which I assume was generally translated as *great*, since its range of meanings is much broader than *large*. (E.g., Charlemagne was called Carolus Magnus, or Charles the Great. Charles the Large wouldn't have meant the same thing at all.) Thus, *major* would naturally be translated as *greater*.

*Minor* is the comparative form of [*parvus*,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parvus#Latin) which again has a much broader meaning than *small* (*small, cheap, ignorable, unimportant*). 
The natural opposite of *greater* in English that is compatible with this broader meaning would be *less* or *lesser*.

Comment: Good answer. But it motivates a follow-up: Why not "lesser than" instead of "less than"?

Answer (score 3):

As you might suspect, the symbols (and thus their names) come to us from the world of mathematics.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign):

> The symbols < and > first appear in Artis Analyticae Praxis ad Aequationes Algebraicas Resolvendas (‘The Analytical Arts Applied to Solving Algebraic Equations’)...

So, in the world of math, as I understand it, *less* is not the same as *smaller*.

But then, why *greater* instead of *more*?  According to [this page](http://www.gmatpill.com/more-than-vs-greater-than-vs-less-than-fewer-than/):

> The 3 Rules for MORE/GREATER/LESS/FEWER than…
>
> 1. If COUNTABLE (dogs, apartments, opportunities, agencies, people)
>      -> then Use MORE/FEWER than combination
> 2. If COUNTABLE, but related to time, distance, or money OR if
>      NOT-COUNTABLE
>      -> then Use MORE/LESS than combination
> 3. For BOTH COUNTABLE & NOT-COUNTABLE, if there is a comparison made
>      between the LEVEL or DEGREE or NUMBER of something
>      -> then Use GREATER THAN/LESS THAN combination

So, because there is a comparison going on, we use greater than/less than.  (Note that that site includes no references, but if you want something more definitive, I'm sure that the Google can help out.)

Comment: I think the question is *why* rule #3. It sounds like a "rule" that just reflects usage. In that case, this answer is "just because".

Comment: To answer that question, you're going to have to find someone smarter and more knowledgeable than I.

Comment: And I............

Answer (score 0):

Surely this confusion comes from using the same mathematical symbols to compare differing data types. Not only are they applied to both countable and noncountable entities, in computer programming, they are applied to dates.  In which case, we should be using 'earlier than' and 'later than'.  In theory, this could also include other comparisons, such as 'higher than' and 'lower than'.  Why 'greater than' and 'less than' have passed into common usage, is probably due to the vast majority of people abandoning the grammatical difference between a number and a quantity and 'great than' just sounds weird, whereas 'less than' doesn't, for some strange reason, which I can only attribute to good old common usage.